# Memory increase when using RenderTargetBitmap on 32 bit images

Tags: c#, wpf

We are encountering a strange problem when creating preview screenshots of UserControls within our application. If a user control contains a 32 bit png image, the memory used for the image creation is not released afterwards, while there is apparently no problem when only 24 bit images are used.

The UserControls are created by users and are loaded into our application. Within the application, at some time we are creating preview images of those controls using `RenderTargetBitmap.Render()` and a `PngBitmapEncoder` + `FileStream` to save it as an image. The memory increase happens when calling the Render method and it is never freed.

This behaviour can be reproduced in a [sample application](https://github.com/ardmog/demoapp/tree/main):

- 2 UserControls are created consisting of only 1 image, on the first encoded with a 32 bit png, on the second with a 24 bit png. This image is a simple image with the dimension 2500x2500px, only containing colored noise, no transparency.

Control 1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1">
  <StackPanel >
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/images/noise3x32.png" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Control 2:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl2">
  <StackPanel >
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/images/noise3x24.png" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

- A content control is placed on the main window

  ```
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl x:Name="UCContentControl" ></ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
  ```
- The UC is loaded into the content control

  ```
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
        UCContentControl.Content = uc1;
  ```
- A render target bitmap is created and render is called

  ```
        var uc = UCContentControl.Content as FrameworkElement;

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(1888, 968, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        rtb.Render(uc);
  ```

[The full demo app is available at github](https://github.com/ardmog/demoapp/tree/main)

When executing this sample, we notice the following:

[Application memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDIfi.png)
(unfortunately, I can't post images yet)

Loading the 32 bit image UserControl takes memory for the UC itself, as expected. Creating a RenderTargetBitmap and calling render increases the memory consumption further. This memory is consumed as long as the Control exists. Unloading the Control releases the memory. However, this behaviour can only be reproduced with 32 bit png images, doing the same with 24 bit png images causes no further memory increase.

Unfortunately, we can't simply unload our controls in our actual application. So, this poses the questions:

- How can the memory consumed upon calling RenderTargetBitmap.Render be freed without unloading the control?
- What exactly keeps the memory from being released? Does the UserControl hold any references?
- Why does this only happen with 32 bit PNGs?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you or not, but your claim that "24 bit png images causes no further memory increase" isn't true from my observations. It's subtle, but it appears to have the same problem as your 32-bit images. See [video of performance profile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/111NIYubOyd9Xigq3pEIqI2Yc8B---uCb/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: You shouldn't think in terms of PNG, rather, in what bitmap format it is converted to. Also, you can always step through .NET framework to understand the internals though it's likely to be a huge task in itself.

Comment: @TamBui; Thank you for your video. When I try these steps, the memory remains in use, even after closing the UC, but is freed upon the next call of the GC. About 6 KB seem to remain, but compared to the huge amount of the 32 bit image this is only a small amount. Unfortunately, I can't reord videos, but here is a [screenshot:](https://imgur.com/a/S16KUwU)

Another interesting thin is, that your memory impact when loading the control seems to be quite a lot lower compared to mine, almost only half as much.

Comment: @aybe: I get the same effect when using other image types. If I try GIFs or TIFFs, I get the same behaviour as with the 32 bit PNG, if I try BMP or JPG, I get the same behaviour as the 24 bit PNG. What the RenderTargetBitmap does to the images (or the control itself), I unfortunately don't know.

 I am wondering if transparency has anything to do with it.

Comment: Few things #1 it is not all that uncommon that a WPF app takes ~300Mb #2 you may want to profile over a long time if usage really blows up #3 if the control is visible on the screen, you may to take a shot using a lower level method like GDI/Win32/native/etc, basically it would cost zero